# How to make sure file saved by using cURL

Tags: php

```
<?php
$source = 'http://www.xxx.com/1.jpg';
$fileBody = date('YmdHis') . rand(1000, 9999);
$extension = pathinfo($source, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$fileName = $fileBody . '.' . $extension;

$ch = curl_init($source);
$fp = fopen($path . $fileName, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
clearstatcache();

return $fileName;
```

This is how I grab image from internet, the image saved successfully and I will return file name for ajax to make immediately thumbnail, but sometimes php return the $fileName when it still processing download, therefore JavaScript reveal empty image on the page, how response after the file indeed been download.

Comment: would this not look a bit simpler with `$file = file_get_contents($url);` then `file_put_contents($filename);`, i'm not sure if it is quicker but it sure looks much easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`curl_exec`](http://php.net/curl_exec) returns `true` on success and `false` on failure. Use that information.

Also, You can check [`curl_getinfo`](http://php.net/curl_getinfo)  to make sure the transfer completed successfully and was not empty. (You get `http_code` there for example, as well as `content_type` and `size_download`).

Comment: However, if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is set, `curl_exec()` will return the **result on success**, FALSE on failure.

Comment: @djay True, but in this case the OP uses `CURLOPT_FILE` to save the file rather than getting the response inside php...

Answer (score 1):

```
$downComplete = false;
while(!$downComplete)
{
   if(!file_exist($filePath))
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
    else
    {
     $downComplete = true; 
     break;
    }
}
```

Hi,Above is an idea for check if file is completely downloaded,i think it's useful,
main idea is check saved file all the time until its finished download,then you can
display the img to front end..you can add it after your curl code,i didn't run it 
myself,so just an idea..